CORS request was blocked despite having origin in header
This is my first time deploying a full stack app to production. I have containerized my frontend and backend and hosted both on google run cloud. When I test both containers locally everything works. When I test the code locally I also have no CORS issues.
However, on production when launching the google cloud instance I get the following cors error:

A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request.
To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values.

Below is my server.js file where as you can see i have specified the .env value:
I already set the env variables in google cloud run for both the frontend and backend. I.e. the CORS_ORIGIN has been set as an env variable with the google cloud run instance.
However, this still does not work
// server.js

// 1. Load Environment Variables
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const HOST = "0.0.0.0";

// 2. Import Required Modules
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const xss = require("xss-clean");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken"); // For JWT handling

// 3. Initialize Express App
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

// 4. Import Routes
app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => {
  res.status(204).end();
});

const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const classRoutes = require("./routes/classRoutes");
const classroomRoutes = require("./routes/classroomRoutes");
const sseRoutes = require("./routes/sseRoutes");

// 5. Import Middleware
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
const authenticate = require("./middleware/authenticate"); // Authentication middleware

// 6. Import SSE Clients
const { clients } = require("./controllers/sseController");

// 7. Make SSE Clients Accessible in app.locals for Broadcasting
app.locals.clients = clients;

// ===========================
// ========== CORS Middleware ========== //
console.log(process.env.CORS_ORIGIN);
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    credentials: true, // Allow cookies to be sent
  })
);

// ===========================
// ========== Security Middlewares ========== //

// 8. Set Secure HTTP Headers using Helmet
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        imgSrc: ["'self'", "data:"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", "data:"],
        connectSrc: [
          "'self'",
          process.env.CORS_ORIGIN, // Ensure this matches your frontend's URL
        ],
      },
    },
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false, // Adjust based on your application's needs
  })
);

// 9. Global Rate Limiting to Prevent Brute-Force and DoS Attacks
const globalLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 1000, // Limit each IP to 1000 requests per windowMs
  standardHeaders: true, // Return rate limit info in the `RateLimit-*` headers
  legacyHeaders: false, // Disable the `X-RateLimit-*` headers
  message: {
    success: false,
    message:
      "Too many requests from this IP, please try again after 15 minutes.",
  },
});

// Apply the global rate limiter to all requests
app.use(globalLimiter);

// 10. Parse Cookies
app.use(cookieParser());

// 11. Body Parsing Middleware
app.use(express.json({ limit: "10kb" })); // Limit JSON payloads to 10KB

// 12. Data Sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());

// ===========================
// ========== Routes ========== //

// 13. Mount API Routes
app.use("/", authRoutes);
app.use("/", classRoutes);
app.use("/", classroomRoutes);
app.use("/", sseRoutes);

// // 14. Serve Static Front-End Files
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend/public")));

// // 15. Catch-All Route to Serve Front-End Application
// app.get("*", (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend/public", "index.html"));
// });

// ===========================
// ========== Error Handling ========== //

// 16. Centralized Error Handling Middleware
app.use(errorHandler);

// ===========================
// ========== Start Server ========== //

server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(` Server is running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
  

Frontend Docker File:
FROM node:18-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

RUN npm install -g serve

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD ["serve", "-s", "-l", "4200", "./build"]

Backend Docker File:
FROM node:18-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "./server.js"]

Error Message
Example of API Call:
const response = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`,
        {
          email,
          password,
        }
      );

Where REACT_APP_API_URL is the URL of the google cloud backend instance and is specified as an env variable in the frontend instance

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

I believe that the call to app.use(cors(... should come before any route declaration.

To debug a CORS problem, you must analyze the HTTP request and response headers plus the HTTP Status Code. Your code includes Authorization and credentials. Review how that works with CORS and with Google Cloud Run authorization. My guess is that the Cloud Run GFE is processing the client request and rejecting it with an HTTP Status Code error value. The browser confuses you by reporting a CORS error instead of an HTTP error.
